# Error when trying to open sqlite database connection

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-sqlite

I have an interface

```
SQLiteConnection _connection = Getconnection();

public SQLite.SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
{
        const string sqliteFilename = "TCRMobile.db3";
        string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); // Documents folder
        var dbPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, sqliteFilename);
        return new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.FullMutex, false);
 }
```

So when I kill my app or in any random case, the app crashed. And App Center says reason for crash as:

```
Cache.get_Connection ()
System.InvalidOperationException: You MUST call Xamarin.Forms.Init(); prior 
to using it.
Device.get_PlatformServices ()
Device.GetAssemblies ()
DependencyService.Initialize ()
DependencyService.Get[T] (Xamarin.Forms.DependencyFetchTarget fetchTarget)
Cache.get_Connection ()
TCRMobile.DataAccess.DataAccessBase..cctor () [0x00005] in 
<7ccb325064fd467288e39511a2bcad63>:0
```

I added `global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);` in *MainActivity.cs* file. But still it crashes.

Any help?

Comment: are you calling GetConnection() before you call Forms.Init?  Where is the call to GetConnection located?

Comment: I put my app in debug mode. When app is launched it first came to forms.init and then GetConnection().

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that in your *MainActivity.cs* (Android) / *AppDelegate.cs* (iOS) the `Forms.Init` gets called before the making of the *App*.

So something like this would be the correct approach

```
  global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
  LoadApplication(new App());
```

If the above is correct, check the flow.
You should have

- An interface in your portable class

`public interface ISQLite
{
        SQLiteConnection GetConnection();
}`

- An implementation for each platform (so iOS/Android/UWP) containing an `assembly` tag

**Android** example

`[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(SqLiteAndroid))]
 namespace Your.Namespace.Droid
{

      public class SqLiteAndroid:ISQLite
      {
         public SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
         {
            //return connection here
         }
      }
}`

and **iOS** example, same principle **but notice the different namespace and *assembly***

`[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(SqLiteiOS))]
 namespace Your.Namespace.iOS
{

      public class SqLiteiOS:ISQLite
      {
         public SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
         {
            //return connection here
         }
      }
}`

- A call to the `DependencyService` to get the connection e.g. in your *App.xaml.cs*

`string sqlConnection= DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection()`

Let me know if this works for you, if not, please provide some more code.

Comment: I'm doing the same. But When I guess When I'm killing the swiping it, xamarin forms losing its initialization and when we are trying to access connection in the background, it is getting crash. Is this correct? if so what is the solution?

Comment: Could you update your post with some more code? Like your _MainActivity.cs_ , your `SqLite` code and where your code crashes. That way it would be easier for me to help you, if possible

Comment: i also follow everything same but GetConnection() method not called as i didn't get call in this method .